# TensorFlow unexpected addition result

Tags: tensorflow

I am running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable(5.0)
```

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

The following gives different results:

```
y = x + y  
for i in xrange(10):
    print sess.run(y, {x: 1.0})
```

Gives:
6, 6, 6, 6, ...

Compare with:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    y = x + y    
    print sess.run(y, {x: 1.0})
```

Prints:
6,7,8,9 ...

Why is the result different?
I thought that:

```
sess.run(y, {x: 1.0})
```

Does:
    y = x + 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time `y = x + y` is executed, computational graph changes, i.e. in first iteration you add `y = x + y` to your graph, and so on.

Comment: The question is why does the first loop does not change the value of y?

Comment: That's how tensorflow works. In fact, computational graph is just a function which has some internal variables (y in your case) and could accept some values (x) for computing other values as combinations of variables and placeholders. First for loop doesn't change graph, just evaluating y = y + x which is 6 for y = 5 and x = 1.